# python selenium get content of table

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape a website using python selenium bindings.

I want to get the content of a table using selenium.

I am quite new to python and selenium so please excuse my ignorance.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.designmynight.com/london/bars/soho/six-storeys')

hours = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="hours"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="hours"]').click()

hoursTable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.opening-hours")

print hoursTable
```

Comment: Your css selector is not unique. What exactly on page you are trying to click?

Comment: ah ok, it needs to be unique. I actually want to click on each one, then go and get data from each page.

Comment: In that case provide all the links with their html you wanted to click

Comment: What data you want ?

Comment: @RaulRodriguez if you want solution for your answer better create a project on freelancer or on upwork. this is the place where you ask question which can't easily goodle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to get required values:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.designmynight.com/london/bars/soho/six-storeys')

hours = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="hours"]')
hours.click()

hoursTable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table.opening-times tr")
for row in hoursTable:
    print(row.text)
```

Note that `class` name of `table` is not `"opening-hours"`, but `"opening-times"`

Output:

```
'Day Open Close Notes'
'Monday 08:00 00:00'
'Tuesday 08:00 00:00'
'Wednesday 08:00 00:00'
'Thursday 08:00 01:00'
'Friday (today) 08:00 02:00'
'Saturday 10:00 02:00'
'Sunday 10:00 00:00'
```

Comment: the king of selenium! :-) do you have any ideas how I can achieve the following - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875664/click-on-element-with-classname-selenium